# Replace value in one dataframe with value in another if three columns match

Tags: python, pandas, find, compare

I have two data arrays as seen below.

I need to look at only A and B values and match the f_code (F in Data2) and b_ID (B in Data2). If they match, I replace the 'value' in Data1 with the A or B value for that row in Data2. So I want to end up with a new Data1 with the 'value' column reflecting the numbers in Data2.

I've been trying to find where the two matches by masking out the places that don't match, but then it's hard to end up with the original Data1, but just with the parts that need to be changed edited.

```
Data1_masked = Data1[Data1['F_Code'].isin(Data2['F'])]
```

I also considered writing a for loop, but I'm new to Python so I've not writing it the right way

```
for a in Data1['F_Code']:
    for b in Data1['B_ID']:
        if a.isin(Data2['F']) and b.isin(Data2('B') and FF10['poll'].loc[a] == 'A'
              FF10['Value'] = Data2['A']
 for a in Data1['F_Code']:
    for b in Data1['B_ID']:
        if a.isin(Data2['F']) and b.isin(Data2('B') and FF10['poll'].loc[a] == 'B'
              FF10['Value'] = Data2['B']
```

Data1

```
Species Value   F_Code  B_ID
C   0.00219819  55933   A1
A   0.382345    55933   A1
B   0.023   55933   A1
C   0.001973105 55933   A2
A   0.313388    55933   A2
B   0.00643 55933   A2
C   0.0733  6002    1
A   2377.9  6002    1
B   2354.1  6002    1
C   0.0738  6002    2
A   2998.6  6002    2
B   531 6002    2
C   0.0739  6002    3
A   3340    6002    3
B   510 6002    3
C   0.0781  6002    4
A   2307.2  6002    4
B   326.5   6002    4
A   0.00203     
B   7.47E-05        
C   0.13872 55510   GT-1
A   1.95    55510   GT-1
B   0.11    55510   GT-1
C   0.05    55542   2
A   2.3 55542   2
B   0.1 55542   2
C   0.05    55542   1
A   2.28    55542   1
B   0.09    55542   1
```

Data2

```
F   B   A   B
6002    1   2.54E+06    3.37E+05
6002    2   3.42E+06    4.70E+05
6002    3   5.35E+06    4.99E+05
6002    4   4.71E+06    4.84E+05
55510   GT-1    1.87E+03    1.03E+02
55542   1   6.72E+03    2.30E+02
55542   2   6.98E+03    2.47E+02
55933   A1  2.50E+04    1.42E+03
55933   A2  2.79E+04    1.56E+03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your second `DataFrame` a bit, that way you can then merge them together and replace the Value column when those three columns match. The important step here is `.stack()` which will make it so that a row in `df2` represents a distinct `Species, Facility, Boiler` combination, which is how `df1` is organized.

```
# Clean df2
df2 = (df2.rename(columns={'a': 'A'})
          .set_index(['F', 'B'])
          .stack()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={'level_2': 'Species', 0: 'Value', 
                           'F': 'f_code',
                           'B': 'B_ID'}))

# Bring information to df1
ids = ['f_code', 'B_ID', 'Species']
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=ids, how='left', suffixes=['', '_repl'])

# Replace value where necessary, then drop the column we no longer need
df1.loc[df1.Value_repl.notnull(), 'Value'] = df1.loc[df1.Value_repl.notnull(), 'Value_repl']
df1 = df1.drop(columns='Value_repl')
```

Output: `df1`

```
   Species          Value  f_code B_ID
0      C       0.002198   55933.000000      TPP1
1      A   25000.000000   55933.000000      TPP1
2      B    1420.000000   55933.000000      TPP1
3      C       0.001973   55933.000000      TPP2
4      A   27900.000000   55933.000000      TPP2
5      B    1560.000000   55933.000000      TPP2
6      C       0.073300    6002.000000         1
7      A 2540000.000000    6002.000000         1
8      B  337000.000000    6002.000000         1
9      C       0.073800    6002.000000         2
10     A 3420000.000000    6002.000000         2
11     B  470000.000000    6002.000000         2
12     C       0.073900    6002.000000         3
13     A 53C.000000    6002.000000         3
14     B  499000.000000    6002.000000         3
15     C       0.078100    6002.000000         4
16     A 4710000.000000    6002.000000         4
17     B  484000.000000    6002.000000         4
18     A       0.002030            nan       NaN
19     B       0.000075            nan       NaN
20     C       0.138720   55510.000000      GT-1
21     A    1870.000000   55510.000000      GT-1
22     B     103.000000   55510.000000      GT-1
23     C       0.0C   55542.000000         2
24     A    6980.000000   55542.000000         2
25     B     247.000000   55542.000000         2
26     C       0.0C   55542.000000         1
27     A    6720.000000   55542.000000         1
28     B     230.000000   55542.000000         1
```